# How to find the smallest cardinal of a minimal generating set of a lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Suppose that $L$ is a sublattice of the power set of $X$.

Is there any algorithm for finding a minimal generating set of $L$ which has the smallest possible cardinality? If we have the cardinality of $L$, what we can say about the cardinality of the smallest minimal genrating set of $L$?

Thanks for your helps in advance.